# Send a JavaScript array as a JSON value?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, post, arrays

How can I send a JavaScript array as a JSON variable in my AJAX request?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This requires you to serialize the javascript array into a string, something that can easily be done using the JSON object.

```
var myArray = [1, 2, 3];
var myJson = JSON.stringify(myArray); // "[1,2,3]"
....
xhr.send({
    data:{
        param: myJson
    }
});
```

As the JSON object is not present in older browsers you should include Douglas Crockfords [json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) library

If you already rely on some library that includes methods for encoding/serializing then you can use this instead. E.g. ExtJs has `Ext.encode`

Comment: So all it does it create a string: "[1,2,3]"... But what if I want to send a string that starts and ends with [], will the server side be able to tell the difference?

Comment: Did you not say JSON? That is per definition just the format of the content of a string. If you in fact wanted to send an _array_ to the server then that is a different question.
But having said that, if one of the elements in the array contains [ or ] then it will automatically be escaped by the serializing method.

Comment: I tried a fixed example by sending the "[1,2,3]" string to the server using ajax/json. But when I check the received value with $val[0] it gives me: "[". Do I need to process the json array on the server side before I can use it?

Comment: $val is still a string - if you want this as an array (with items of some type) then you will need to decode it. I'm guessing your using php so you could try json_decode http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: One thing you need to remember is that in the browser you have ECMAScript (javascript), and on the server you have PHP (I'm guessing). These are different languages and hence has different types. JSON is a 'language' understood by both, but one that only supports a subset of each one. So only primitives like strings, numbers and booleans are supported as well as basic arrays, indexed and associative (literal object notation).

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using a javascript library (jQuery, prototype.js, etc) that will do this for you, you can always use the [example code from json.org](http://www.json.org/js.html)

Answer (score 1):

Just encode the array and send it as part of your AJAX recuest:

http://www.openjs.com/scripts/data/json_encode.php

There are too many others encoders, or even plugins for JQuery and Mootools :D

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

```
 var arr = [1, 2, 3];
 $.ajax({
        url: "get.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {ids:arr},
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

In get.php:

```
echo json_encode($_POST['ids']);
```

Array will be converted to object using {ids:arr}, pass the object itself and letting jQuery do the query string formatting.